# Case Insensitive (Not Case Sensitive) Search with Swift 2

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a class in Parse called "Friends". I added a search bar (without a search display controller). I want to be able to search for "John Doe" by searching for "john doe". The only way I have been able to do it is by making the 'friends' under `"first_name"` and `"last_name"` in Parse all lower case. I then convert my searchBar.text to a lowerCaseString and it works. I can't seem to convert `"first_name"` or `"last_name"` to a `lowerCaseString`. 
Any ideas? Thanks!

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!


var searchResults = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Search word = \(searchBar.text!)")


    let firstNameQuery = PFQuery(className:"Friends")
    firstNameQuery.whereKey("first_name".lowercaseString, matchesRegex: searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)



    let lastNameQuery = PFQuery(className:"Friends")
    lastNameQuery.whereKey("last_name".lowercaseString, matchesRegex: searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)

    // lastNameQuery.whereKey("last_name", matchesRegex: "(?i)\(searchBar.text)") <- Instead of firstNameQuery.whereKey("first_name", containsString: searchBar.text)






    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([firstNameQuery, lastNameQuery])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

            myAlert.addAction(okAction)

            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }

        if let objects = results as? [PFObject] {

            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in objects {
                let firstName = object.objectForKey("first_name") as! String
                let lastName = object.objectForKey("last_name") as! String
                let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName

                self.searchResults.append(fullName)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
                self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

            }



        }




    }

}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    return myCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mySearchBar.text = ""
}

@IBAction func refreshButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    mySearchBar.text = ""
    self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}


}
```

Comment: Possibly try undercasing and uppercasing the search (first letter) so it will match any single word.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSStringCompareOption for the case insensitive search. If you use this function then the results would show all the string that contain the substring.

```
let range = temp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
if range.location != NSNotFound {
    print("match")
}
```

If you just want the results that start with a particular search string. Just check if the range starts from the first character of the string.

Comment: Still unsure as to how I would implement that into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the both text into Lowercased(search text and array string)

```
   let text = searchText.lowercased()
        filtered = data.filter({

            let t = $0.dr_name.lowercased().contains(text)
           
            if t{
                return true
            }else{
                 return false
            }
           
            
        })
```

Comment: That seems convoluted, why not just return `$0.dr_name.lowercased().contains(text)` as that will be a boolean value